# Surround two words with quotes in Vim

Tags: vim, surround

I am working with vim-surround and the following text. (* is the place of the cursor)

```
This is a lo*ng line and I want to highlight two words
```

I want to surround both the words long and line within quotes, so that it becomes

```
This is a "long line" and I want to highlight two words
```

Is it possible to do it without getting into visual mode?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try: `ys2w"` (`ys` takes a motion or text object, and then the character with which you want to surround).

Comment: This will work if my cursor is at *long, but since my cursor is at lo*ng, it become lo(ng line)

Comment: To avoid having to move first: `ys2aw"`

Answer (score 6):

Press `b` first and then `ys2w"`

Answer (score 3):

When using surround commands, I find the most logical solution is to sequence the "marking" and the "surrounding" operations.

Thus, with text objects, I use v2aw to visually mark the two words, then s" for the total of

```
v2aws"
```

Comment: I have tied it. Seem like it is surrounding only for the first word

Comment: Huh? v2iw will visually mark two inner words. s" will surround the visual selection with "". Can you give a sample text and cursor location where it does not work?

Comment: Actually, I have the same problem that you describe on my Mac version of Vim. I wonder if there's some incompatibility... I'll look into it.

Comment: Cool. Please do comment when you figure it out. It will be helpful.

Comment: It works with "a" word instead of "inner" word. I will update my answer.