# Some Surround.vim commands don't work

Tags: vim, plugins

Just installed the surround.vim plugin and some of the commands don't work as expected. I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258143/surround-two-words-with-quotes-in-vim) as an example

```
This is a lo*ng line and I want to highlight two words
```

a `ys2aw"` should change the above to

```
This is a "long line" and I want to highlight two words
```

but for me it changes it to

```
This is a g and I want to highlight two words
```

Other times it has no affect at all! I think it has to do with what is in the yanked register.

When I am typing `ys`, in the bottom right I can see that it quickly changes to `g@`

Finally, I am pretty sure no other plugins are interfering as by issuing the `verbose map yss` command:

```
 n  yss           <Plug>Yssurround
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/surround.vim                                                                                                                     
 n  ys            <Plug>Ysurround
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/surround.vim
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the bug. Where exactly do you have your cursor? On the `o` or on the `n`?

Comment: @romainl I just tried it again over the "o". If I yank it into vim, go over the "o" and issue the command `ys2aw"` I get: `This is a "This is a "long line" and I want to highlight two words" and I want to highlight two words     
`

Comment: @romainl if I undo and issue the command again, I get the same behavior, but with a new line before and after the pasted inside quote. If I then undo and redo yet again, nothing appears to change (although the file is listed as being modified)

Comment: @romainl I think I figured it out, in my vim file I have set it such that gnome and vim use the same clipboard (`set clipboard=unnamedplus`) and commenting this out removes the problem so I guess surround uses the unnamed register somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, to make it easier to copy/paste between vim and, well, everything else, I had the following rule in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

This makes `surround.vim` behave incorrectly. Instead what I did was add the following line to my `.vimrc` file to allow me to toggle this desired behaviour on/off

```
nnoremap <leader>hf :set clipboard=unnamedplus<CR>
nnoremap <leader>fh :set clipboard-=unnamedplus<CR>
```

and now `surround.vim` works as normal

Comment: Crap! I'm very sorry: I experienced a similar problem a long time ago and solved it exactly like that. I should have remembered.

Comment: Please report this to the plugin's author (i.e. open a GitHub issue); many plugins temporarily reset `'clipboard'` to avoid such interference.